# Project Type on Codenvy

Tags: github, repository, codenvy

I've forked a the spoon-knife demo repository on github and am importing it to my Codenvy IDE.  Codenvy asks me to "select the project type" from a drop down menu that includes: PHP, Rails, and a dozen other options.  Is there one correct option or will any project type allow me to work on this repo?

Answer (score 0):

You may select Blank type and then select Java/Web/Tomcat7 runner

Answer (score 0):

Within Codenvy, a project type and a runner environment are separate concepts.  The project type defines behaviors of the project with instructions on how to map source files and builders.  Project type is primarily about designating the right information for editors and associated plug-ins, but will not have a significant bearing on how you run the project.

The runner environment is associated separately. The runner environment can be provided by Codenvy or yourself. These are docker containers that will run your code.  So if you select a blank project type, you have your choice of runner environments later on.  In some cases, project type will narrow the list of available system runner environments.  For example if you choose a maven project, you will not be given the PHP runner environment options.  The blank project type leaves all runner environment options available.

At any time, you can override the system runner environments with one of your own.  You can write a custom environment as a Dockerfile with the Run With... entry.